# Python Pandas Series.str.contains

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data that looks like this in a CSV file:
[image]

Is it possible to print a Boolean statement if the ***dataframe columns names*** are `MAT` and `OAT` and `RAT`?

Is pandas series needed for this? Like [Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)?

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('static/data.csv')


#OAT = pd.Series(df['OAT'])
#RAT = pd.Series(df['RAT'])
#MAT = pd.Series(df['MAT'])

dfS = pd.Series(df)

print(dfS.str.contains('OAT', 'MAT', 'RAT'))
```

Comment: You want to check the column names, which you can access with ```df.columns```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `issubset` method to return boolean if `['OAT', 'MAT', 'RAT']` is in the dataframe's columns:

```
expected = set(['OAT', 'MAT', 'RAT'])
print(expected.issubset(df.columns))
```

Answer (score 0):

Work on the columns of the dataframe.

```
mask = df.columns.isin(['OAT', 'MAT', 'RAT'])
```

`mask` is now a boolean `numpy.ndarray` with `True` for any column position 
that matches your 'isin' list.